# pySerial conexion de arduino, y python

Tags: python, arduino

Amigos estoy conectando un arduino a mi pc y quiero recolectar datos desde el arduino a python tengo en mi arduino este codigo

```
void loop() { 
  valor_alcohol=analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println(valor_alcohol);       // Envia al Serial el valor leido del Sensor MQ3 
  float porcentaje=(valor_alcohol/10000);  //calcula el porcentaje
  Serial.println(porcentaje);            // Envia al Serial el porcentaje 
  Serial.println(' ');
```

y en python tengo este codigo y funciona bien

```
# Declaramos unas variable para almacenar el puerto, codificacion, tiempo de cada peticion
arduino = serial.Serial('COM2', 9600, timeout=4)

# ciclo para siempre tomar lectura
while True:
    rawString = arduino.readline()
    porcentaje = rawString / 10000
    print(rawString)

    if rawString == 400:
        print('Estas Borracho con un porcentaje de {}'.format(porcentaje))
```

y en la consola de python veo esto:

```
b'52.00\r\n'
b'52.00\r\n'
b'53.00\r\n'
b'52.00\r\n'
b'52.00\r\n'
b'52.00\r\n'
b'52.00\r\n'
b'52.00\r\n'
b'51.00\r\n'
b'53.00\r\n'
b'52.00\r\n'
b'52.00\r\n'
b'53.00\r\n'
```

resulta que quiero hacerle un tratamiento a estos datos y pasarlo a float pero me sale el siguiente error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Usuario/Documents/001. Python_grafica/face/arduino.py", line 12, in <module>
    porcentaje = rawString / 10000
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'bytes' and 'int'
```

soy nuevo en python como lo puedo solucionar espero me puedan ayudar amigos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes convertir la variable rawString de **bytes** a **float**:

```
rawString = arduino.readline()

# Se convierte los bytes a string
rawString = str(rawString)

# Se elimina el retorno de carro "\r" y el avance de linea "\n" 
# con la función para cadenas de texto ".replace" con el objetivo que solo quede el número.
rawString = rawString.replace("\r","")
rawString = rawString.replace("\n","")

# Ahora se convierte de string a float que es para números decimales
rawString = float(rawString)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tal como el error especifica:

> Error de tipo: tipo de operando no soportado para /: bytes y entero:

`rawString` es una cadena de `bytes` la cual no puedes dividir entre un entero. Python jamás hace conversiones implícitas de datos por principio (como su propio zen reza; "explícito mejor que implícito").

Debes ser tu el que explícitamente hagas la conversión de la cadena de bytes (que en este caso representa un `float`) al tipo correspondiente.

Por otro lado, el condicional

```
if rawString == 400:
```

**jamás se va a cumplir por la sencilla razón de que `rawString` es de tipo `bytes` y `400` es un literal de `int`**, son dos objetos de distinta clase no comparables entre si. Debes hacer la comparación con `porcentaje` o con la conversión a `float`/`int` de `rawString`.